# Magento custom Static Block not present in template

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.9.1

i am a Magento Newbie.

In the *local.xml* under the *header* section these blocks are defined:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="cms/block" name="flatshop_header_support">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>flatshop_header_support</block_id></action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="flatshop_header_2blocks">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>flatshop_header_2blocks</block_id></action>
    </block>
```

in the *header.phml* both are called like:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('flatshop_header_support') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('flatshop_header_2blocks') ?>
```

On /admin/cms_block/ *static block* with *"flatshop_header_support"* Identifier are defined and filled with content like *"flatshop_header_2blocks"* (this is working well), but the return is `string(0) ""`

How can i print *flatshop_header_support* block in the header section?

*Magento v1.9.1 template: Flathop*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you 3 different ways to solve your issue here.

I would strongly suggest my number (3), it is the best way and would not recommend number (2).

1) just use the below code in your **header.phtml** file instead of what you have used to call the static blocks in your phtml file

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('flatshop_header_support')->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('flatshop_header_2blocks')->toHtml(); ?>
```

2) Instead of *local.xml*, use your "reference block" codes from *local.xml* and paste it in *page.xml* inside

```
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">---</block>
```

it should work as well

3) The script that you are using has no problem, the only thing I could say is, your *local.xml* is not setup correctly which is why it is not executed, look for simple details like xml tags or compare with the code that I am using for *local.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
      <default>
          <reference name="header">
             <block type="cms/block" name="flatshop_header_support">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>flatshop_header_support</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="flatshop_header_2blocks">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>flatshop_header_2blocks</block_id></action>
            </block>
           </reference>
      </default>
    </layout>
```

Hope my answer solves your issue.

Comment: The 1), 2) version are working well. in case of 3) only the `encoding="UTF-8"` was missing. thank You!